# I need ideas to unit test this Tasked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task

This is the method in question:

```
public void StartBatchProcessing(IFileBatch fileBatch)
{
    var dataWarehouseFactsMerger = m_dataWarehouseFactsMergerFactory.Create(fileBatch);
    dataWarehouseFactsMerger.Merge();

    if(!m_isTaskStarted)
    {
        m_isTaskStarted = true;
        m_lastQueuedBatchProcessingTask = new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => ProcessBatch(dataWarehouseFactsMerger));
    }
    else
    {
        m_lastQueuedBatchProcessingTask = m_lastQueuedBatchProcessingTask.ContinueWith(previous => ProcessBatch(dataWarehouseFactsMerger));
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using TPL to queue tasks one after the other and I would like to test that the tasks will execute in the order they arrive as soon as the previous one finishes.

The ProcessBatch method is protected so I think it could be overwritten in a derived class and be used to set some flag or something and assert that.

All ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Is `StartBatchProcessing` called on one thread, or on multiple threads?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That one is called on a single thread but, does that really matter? I just want to test the logic within the method so it would run on a single thread in the test anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an implementation of `DataWarehouseFactsMergerFactory` that creates implementations of `DataWarehouseFactsMerger` that are capable of logging which `fileBatch` was entered and the start time of each task, but for the rest don't really do anything.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Is it possible that you add a small example?

Comment: That's hard because I can't see your types, but if you make interfaces like `IDataWarehouseFactsMergerFactory` and `IDataWarehouseFactsMerger` you could make implementations for real life and for testing. `ProcessBatch` should accept an `IDataWarehouseFactsMerger` then.

Comment: I think I understand, basically the ProcessBatch method would need to be overriden to log the time when each task started and they should be in ascending order right?

Comment: Maybe, yes. You know your code. As long as you can do a test run without doing the real (time consuming) stuff it is OK. That would make a good unit test.